# Repository Directory Structure & Folders for Query Data Problems/Missing/Errors

Tags: document-repository

Can anyone provide examples of putting together a document-repository file directory structure with folders for Querying Missing/Error/Problem Data, in SQL Server?

As far as I've been able to put together so far is, for instance, Document Repositories with SharePoint Server.

MyRepository –> ROOT –> Production -> Customers (break it down into different folders?)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.